# Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService

Tags: typescript, postman, nestjs

I got error like this:

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure 
that the argument Usersinterface at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Usersinterface is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
- If Usersinterface is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported 
within UsersModule?

```
 @Module({
imports: [ /* the Module containing Usersinterface */ ]
  })
```

I got many answers for this problem but that answers are little different from my problem.In my issue i got error on interface rather than any controller or service.

Here is the code of usersinterface:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'

export interface Usersinterface  extends mongoose.Document {
    readonly username: string;
    readonly password: string;
}
```

Here is the code of Usersmodule:

```
@Module({
  imports:[],
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Here is the code of appmodule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [AppModule,UsersModule,MongooseModule.forRoot("mongodb://localhost:27017/test",{ useNewUrlParser: true })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the code of UsersService:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    private hashLength = 16;
    constructor(@Inject('Usersinterface') private readonly userModel:Model<Usersinterface>) {}
```

Comment: Where is you `UsersService` code?You know, the service you're having problems with

Comment: updated my question with UsersService code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I just answered in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387283/how-to-inject-interface-in-module-of-nestjs-app) you need to give the module the correct context of what providers are available. To do this, you need to add `MongooseMOdule.forFeature([schemaObject])` to your `UsersModule`'s `imports` array. In the end, it should look like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeautre([{ name: 'Usersinterface', schema: UsersSchema }]) // you need to create the UsersSchema,
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  private hasLength = 16;
  // make sure this string matches the value in the MongooseModule.forFeature's name property
  constructor(@InjectModel('Usersinterface') private readonly userModel: Model<UsersInterface>) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the dependency injection and not with your interface. Although you haven't posted the code of your app.component.ts file, I think, it is very likely that you have a constructor like

```
constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
```

with the **UserService** injected. The problem is, that you have the **UserService** not provided in the **AppModule** but in the **UserModule**. Please provide the service in the **AppModule** instead or inject the **UserService** only in controllers that you declare in the **UserModule** (which is probably the best way).